# Importing aws4 into an Angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am trying to use the [`aws4` package](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) to sign some requests in an Angular2 TypeScript2 app. I have installed the package and it is in `node_modules`.

In my `component.ts` file, I try to import it with:

```
import * as aws4 from 'aws4';
```

When I build the project with webpack, my code complains `Cannot find module 'aws4'`. However, in the same directory if I start node and run `require('aws4')` it works, so the module is there and has been installed.

`@types/aws4` is also not available.

The interesting thing is that even though TypeScript complains it can't find `aws4` it seems to still get imported properly anyway. However, I get a different error in the browser: `querystring.escape is not a function`. I would think that Webpack would build the code such that nodejs dependencies such as `querystring` get pollyfilled.

Is there anything I need to add to my TypeScript code or Webpack to properly use `aws4`?

Comment: What version of TypeScript?

Comment: @pe8ter Typescript 2

Answer (score 0):

I can help with your typing problem but not your shimming built-in node module problem:

The TS compiler doesn't know the shape of the `aws4` module so you must supply it. As you say, that module doesn't have typings available through npm which means you need to create typings for it. The minimum you need is a file named "aws4.d.ts" with this one line:

```
declare module "aws4";
```

Import the typing in "component.ts" with `/// <reference path="path/to/aws4.d.ts" />`. If you put the typing in the same directory as "component.ts" then you can skip the `reference` bit.

This minimal typing placates the compiler even though you really didn't tell TS about the true shape of the library.

Note: Just because the TS compiler can't find the dependency doesn't mean it won't emit the import statement into your code. That's why your page still loads `aws4` but later fails on referencing `querystring.escape`.